# Случайное из интервала (min, max)

Tags: javascript

```js
var max = 10;
var min = 5;

console.log(min + Math.random() * max);
```

Правильно ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же сами видите, что неправильно.

```js
var max = 10;
var min = 5;

console.log(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
```

Если нужны только *целые* от `5` до `10`:

```js
var max = 10;
var min = 5;

console.log(Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)));
```